# Hiding Columns In SSRS Report Until Row Group Expanded

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report which consists of approximately 25 columns. There are also three row groups. I'm trying to hide specific columns in the report initially, and only make those columns visible when the row groups are expanded. Here is a screenhot of the report in its collapsed state:

[Collapsed Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG5k.png)

So, when the report is collapsed, I want these four columns hidden: Policy Number, Invoice Number, Transaction Type, Date. These columns should only be visible once the row groups are expanded. See below:

[Report Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcN6h.png)

Another view of the expanded report:
[Expanded Row Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib3c8.png)

I do not have any column groups currently defined, only row groups.

I tried defining a column group using Policy Number as as test, and then set the visibility to an expression:  =iif(IsNothing(fields!Current_Policy_Number.Value), False, True)

That expression hid the column, but when expanding the row groups, the column still stayed hidden.

I've been looking everywhere, but all the options I've found don't seem to fit my exact situation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to implement a custom grouping mechanism.

Use a custom group-icon and a hidden parameter. By default, groups should be hidden. So the visibility for necessary rows and columns should be:

```
=iif(Parameters!CustomGroup.Value = 0, False, True)
```

When user clicks the icon, a parameter is set (reload current report with CustomGroup-parameter set to inverse value) and then the groups are visible.

Comment: We don't want the user to have to do or click anything. The columns should become visible when the Invoice Detail group is expanded. I've tried adding a parent column group on the Policy Number, but that just ends up creating a new column for each specific policy number, essentially making the report huge column wise.  From what I'm seeing, a column group might not be what I'm looking for. It might just be as simple as setting the visibility of the column(s) based on an expression, but can't find the right expression to use. I was hoping this would be a little easier!